# Permission denied while compiling my own code

Tags: c++, permissions, compilation, g++

Using this:

```
g++ -c -Wall -l libuthreads.a test02-new.cc -o test02-new
```

I'm compiling my code.

While trying to execude the code with : test02-new
I get:

```
test02-new: Permission denied.
```

Do you know whats the reason for it?
I used this command before.

Comment: Why are you using `-c`?

Comment: Run `ls -l` in that directly, and post the line for `test02-new`.

Comment: now I run: g++ -Wall -l Libuthreads.a test02-new.cc -o test02-new

Comment: And I get: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lLibuthreads.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `-c` flag, GCC outputs an object file. You cannot execute these.

This should work:

```
$ g++ -Wall libuthreads.a test02-new.cc -o test02-new
$ ./test02-new
```

Comment: @fgfjhgrjrerjhm updated the answer. If `libuthreads.a` is installed globally (rather than in the same directory), you can omit the `-L .` option.

Comment: Its inside the directory... And still I get the Error